# How do I insert a value obtained from a sql sum from one table into another in vb?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

My code is wrong, but this is the closest I can think of to a solution. I'm trying to add up all the points for the specified user from 1 table, and insert that value into another table.  Any help is appreciated.

This is my code:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Leaderboard
Dim MysqlConn As MySqlConnection
Dim COMMAND As MySqlCommand
Private Sub submitBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles    submitBtn.Click
    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString =
    "server=localhost;userid=root;password=root99;database=database"
    Dim READER As MySqlDataReader

    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()

        Dim Query As String
        Query = "  select (select SUM(Points) as sumpoints from database.progress where candidate_number_fk = '" & textbox_can.Text & "') (insert into database.leaderboard (username,points) values ('" & textbox_user.Text & "','  sumpoints '  )"
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
        READER = Command.ExecuteReader
        MessageBox.Show("You have successfully submitted your score")

        MysqlConn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
    My.Forms.Menu1.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need double query as you can use `INSERT INTO .. SELECT FROM` construct and get it done in a single query like

```
insert into database.leaderboard (username,points)
select 'Niam', SUM(Points) as sumpoints 
from database.progress 
where candidate_number_fk = '" & textbox_can.Text & "';
```

Be aware that you are using user input directly in query using string concatenation which may lead to *SQL Injection*. Use parameterized query rather using `MySqlParameter` class.